# Lazarus Pascal: Difference between TFormClass and TPersistentClass

Tags: delphi, freepascal

I've created new form instances like this:

```
var
  ClassToUse: TFormClass;

begin  
  ClassToUse := TfrmMyForm; //CREATED AT DESIGN TIME
.
.
  NewForm := ClassTouse.Create(NewTab); //NewTab is an instance of a tab
.
end;
```

The ABOVE code works fine.

But now I want to send a form as a string to a procedure that would create that form. Thus I changed the code to the following:

I've created new form instances like this:

```
var
  ClassToUse: TFormClass;

begin  
  ClassToUse := GetClass(pFormName); //pFormName is a string -- ERROR IS HERE!!
.
.
  NewForm := ClassTouse.Create(NewTab);  
.
end;
```

This gives the following error:

```
Error: Incompatible types: got "TPersistentClass" expected "TFormClass"
```

Perhaps I'm on the wrong page... What is the right way of implementing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetClass` function returns `TPersistentClass`. You cannot assign one of those to a `TFormClass`. For exactly the same reason why you cannot assign a `TPersistent` reference to a `TForm` reference.

You can change the code to be like so:

```
var
  RegisteredClass: TPersistentClass;
begin  
  RegisteredClass := GetClass(pFormName);
  if RegisteredClass=nil then
    raise ESomeException.Create(...);
  if not RegisteredClass.InheritsFrom(TForm) then
    raise ESomeException.Create(...);
  NewForm := TFormClass(RegisteredClass).Create(NewTab);  
end;
```

Comment: I tried to find the difference between the form class and the persistent class, but I could not find the difference in the Lazarus docs. Knowing they were different, I tried casting the persistent class to TFormClass as well but it never worked and finally brought me to the most unpopular SIGSEGV exception which means "crazy" in my dictionary ;) Thanks for this!

Comment: @David_Heffernan I thought this worked as I had no compile errors but it seems like there's an issue. When the code reaches the lines to create the form, it crashes with SIGSEGV :(

Comment: @David_Heffernan To narrow it down, I did this: **RegisteredClass := GetClass(pFormName);
NewForm := TFormClass(RegisteredClass).Create(NewTab);** And at the creaate line it crashes. BTW, this is Lazarus.

Comment: You omitted all the error checking code that I added. Put it back.

Comment: You see, if `RegisteredClass` really is a `TForm` descendent then your code will work. So clearly it is not. Either that name is not registered. In which case `RegisteredClass` will be `nil`. Or it's registered, but is not a descendent of `TForm`. For the life of me I cannot imagine why you removed the code that would explain the failure!

Comment: @David_Heffernan I put the exceptions in like you gave but I use Exception.Create... It crashes with my error message that the class is not registered. Then I put RegisterClass before the first line in your begin block. But then it just crashes with SIGSEGV. No problem, I'll check this out later. Maybe there's something I'm missing. At least for the moment I can continue using the older method that is not so efficient in terms of code length :( Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why you unaccepted. This is the answer. I fixed your compile error and wrote code that works. The fact that your class is not registered properly is a different subject.

Comment: @David_Heffernan I'm a little lost with the concept of Lazarus, but many thanks to a few folks like you, I've been trying to get the hang of it. My concern is that why my form would be unregistered when I've done it at **design time**? And when I use RegisterClass, it *probabely* crashes at the next line but I can't seem to figure it out. The strange thing is that it **compiles**. The error is only at run-time. Perhaps your answer IS the most correct one but I need to test it further and see where I'm going wrong. And until such time that I get it fixed, here's a +1 for your useful explanation

Comment: The problem is now how to register the class. Which is not the question here. I'm sure we can help clear that up, but it's a new question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any of your problems with `RegisterClass`. I call `RegisterClass` passing `TForm1`. The I call `GetClass('TForm1')` and get returned the appropriate class type. FWIW you should call `RegisterClass` in the unit that declares the class, in its initialization section.

Comment: @David_Heffernan Wow!!! What was that about? I only moved the RegisterClass statement into the initialization part of the forms and they just work like a breeze... But now I'm puzzled... I wonder how this can be? Why didn't it work with RegisterClass in the calling procedure? Well, it seems like I'll have to digest this slowly and I hope I'll conquer the OOP concepts of Lazarus. Coming from an old Pascal/C background, this is a whole new world ;) Thanks again!

Comment: I had no problem with `RegisterClass` in a button handler. I did try that because I wondered whether it might be an issue. In any case, it's a global process wide registration that needs to be done once. The initialization section is the right place for it.

Comment: @David_Heffernan Was that on Lazarus or Delphi? I'm stumped about this whole thing. I never imagined that class registration should be in the initialization section of the module in which the form was declared.

Comment: @David_Heffernan I'm not sure if this matters but my version of Lazarus is 0.9.30.4. What's yours?

Comment: 1.0 but I'd be very surprised if it mattered. Will be down to something in your code that is not present in mine. You should use latest version. By the way, do you find compiling and linking to be astoundingly slow?

Comment: @David_Heffernan My primary OS is Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm running XP on VirtualBox. But I'm not sure if that is a cause for these issues. About being slow... Tell me about it! When I used a P4 with 512Mb, it would take at least 5 minutes to compile. But now on a Core2Duo with 2GB, it takes around 20-30 seconds. But even this is terrible and I hope I get the time to look into all these issues soon. There's another user who has an i3 with 4Gb and that takes an average of about 15 seconds for a single form and a label. But he showed me the same thing on Delphi and it was almost instant.

Comment: When you are used to Delphi, most other compilers are a disappointment when it comes to speed. I've got a fast machine, no VM, loads of memory, and still FPC takes forever. 10-15 seconds for an app with one empty form!!!